# Shiny R Button Alignment

Tags: r, shiny

I have two buttons in my U.i file

```
 submitButton("Analysis"),width=6,downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download Data'))
```

Which gives the following output as the app

[image]

However I am trying to align these buttons so that the download data is right aligned and the analysis button is on the left, instead of how it looks now. How do i go about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do the following. Please look into [shiny 4 small textInput boxes side-by-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637248/shiny-4-small-textinput-boxes-side-by-side) also

```
library(shiny)

ui =fluidPage(
  div(style="display:inline-block",submitButton("Analysis"),width=6),
  div(style="display:inline-block",downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download Data'))
)
server = function(input, output, session){}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

[image]

Comment: I tried that way which does  work better but the outcome is this - http://i.stack.imgur.com/T1wvC.png . I'm trying to get the button on the right side of they grey box and one on the left. I attempted to try this but it didn't work: "div(style="display:inline-block;right-align:". The results after all this is to add another button that is centre aligned but I'm finding this difficult. any ideas how to align the buttons?