# Appearing guide page on Shiny app similar to Radiant's

Tags: r, shiny

Radiant is an amazing Shiny applet that everyone probably knows :  https://vnijs.shinyapps.io/radiant/?SSUID=c730754697

This app benefits from a very nice way of helping its users by using a clickable "?" mark below each sidebar panel, and subsequent appearing document on the page.

May anyone please explain me how to add such help page to my Shiny applet? I could not find the related functions in the codes of this applet.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out R package: `shinyBS`. Where you can use function [bsModal](https://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/docs/Modals.html), i is exactly what you are looking for.

Below is an example app posted on the [github page](https://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/docs/Modals.html), as you can see after pressing the "View Table", pop up appears with the table.

[image]

Additionally to get this nice question mark button, you can use function/ object created with `bsButton()` as a trigger with `bsModal()` together.

--> Here is a link to [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37051631/add-popovers-to-shiny-app) which has an example of shinyBS that might help you.

Comment: Thanks! very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the guide to shiny apps I came across wonderful `rintrojs` package which allows you to build in descriptions of your widgets within `shiny` apps. You can find the description here https://carlganz.github.io/rintrojs/

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(rintrojs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  introjsUI(),
  introBox(actionButton("hide","a"),data.step = 1,data.intro = "By Clicking this button the other one will dissapear"),
  introBox(actionButton("b","b"),data.step = 2,data.intro = "Toggle this button"),br(),
  bsButton("help", label = "About this Page", block = F,style = "primary",icon =icon("question-circle"))
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output,session){

  observeEvent(input$help,introjs(session, options = list("showBullets"="false", "showProgress"="true", "showStepNumbers"="false","nextLabel"="Next","prevLabel"="Prev","skipLabel"="Skip")))

  observeEvent(input$hide,{
    toggle("b")
  })

})
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Radiant uses modals for the help files. In the latest versions of shiny the easiest way to do something like this is with `modelDialog`. See https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/modalDialog.html