# R Shiny multiple Inputs in a row

Tags: r, shiny, numeric-input

It sounds easy, but I'm not able to manage my styling problem. As part of my app I want the user to input `3 numeric inputs` with

```
numericInput(inputid = "good", label ="3*", value =15, min = 0,width = '20px'),
numericInput("ok", "2*",8, min = 0,width = '20px'),
numericInput("bad", "1*",3, min = 0,width = '20px')
```

They are now displayed in 3 large rows in the app.

It would be great for me to arrange them column-wise in one row so I can save some space.

Something like

```
  3*     2*      1*
[15]    [8]     [3]
```

where the second row is illustrating the input fields.

Hope it's getting clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try wrapping them in a `shiny::column`. I'm not certain, but that may force the inputs to display inline, rather than vertically stacked.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/42778604/1017276

Comment: `fluidRow(
            column(1,numericInput("good", "3*",15, min = 0,width = '20px'),offset = 1),
             column(1,numericInput("ok", "2*",8, min = 0,width = '20px'),offset = 2),
             column(1,numericInput("bad", "1*",3, min = 0,width = '20px'),offset = 3)
      )`

Comment: It is also working for me this way.