# Placing two actions buttons beside each other in a shiny app

Tags: css, r, shiny

I am trying to place two action buttons in a Shiny app in a sidebar. Is this at all possible? I don't want to resort to using columns  if I can   keep things simple

```
ui.R:
fluidPage(
 # Application title
 titlePanel("Place Two Buttons"),

 sidebarLayout(
# Sidebar with a slider and selection inputs
sidebarPanel(

  actionButton("read", "Change"),
  hr(),
  actionButton("write", "Change") 
),


mainPanel(
  plotOutput("plot")
  )
)
)
```

and my server :

```
server.R:
function(input, output, session) {

}
```

All what I found so far was using css expressions or using Bootstrappage. Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shiny 4 small textInput boxes side-by-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637248/shiny-4-small-textinput-boxes-side-by-side)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the `hr()` to get the two buttons side by side:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Place Two Buttons"),

  sidebarLayout(
    # Sidebar with a slider and selection inputs
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("read", "Change"),
      actionButton("write", "Change") 
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}
shinyApp( ui = ui, server = server )
```

Which gives this:

[image]

Comment: Mike H: What I meant is to place the two buttons beside each other rather than under each other. Is this possible?

Comment: @owise, Why not just get rid of the `hr()` function?

Comment: @owise - updated. I don't know if you can make the space smaller, but you can probably add some blank UI to increase the space. Unfortunately HTML doesn't have a "vertical rule".

Comment: It worked fine, but when I add in this this expression, it does nnot work: ` withBusyIndicatorUI(actionButton("read", "Change!",  class = "btn-primary")),
      withBusyIndicatorUI(actionButton("write", "Change!",  class = "btn-primary"))`

Comment: @owise Hmm, works fine for me. It might be helpful if you ask a new question with a reproducible example

Comment: @Mikw H. Do you mean it worked for you even when you put it inside the "withBusyIndicationUI"?

Comment: Yes, I copied and pasted the code you wrote into my program and I still got the same result