# splitLayout in shinydashboard::box

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

**Goal**

I want to place an `actionButton` next to a `selectInput` in the footer of a `shinydashboard::box`. According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637248/shiny-4-small-textinput-boxes-side-by-side) `splitLayout` should do what I want.

**Problem**

The `selectInput` does not fill the whole space, when put into the footer. It seems that once in the footer the `selectInput` always takes a fixed width. Funny enough, when the same elements are put into the body of the box, the controls render as foreseen.

**Question**

How do I manage that `selectInput` and the `actionButton`

1. are next to each other AND
2. span the whole line?

**Code**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

boxUI <- function(width) {
  box(
    splitLayout(
      selectInput("x", NULL, paste(strrep("x", 10), 1:10)),
      actionButton("ok", icon("trash")),
      cellWidths = c("85%", "15%"),
      cellArgs = list(style = "vertical-align: top")),
    footer = splitLayout(
      selectInput("y", NULL, paste(strrep("x", 10), 1:10)),
      actionButton("ok", icon("trash")),
      cellWidths = c("85%", "15%"),
      cellArgs = list(style = "vertical-align: top")
    ), width = width, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "info", title = "Box")
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(), 
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(
        HTML(".shiny-split-layout > div {
                  overflow: visible;
              }"))),
    fluidRow(
      boxUI(4),
      boxUI(3))
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you place the `selectInput` inside a `div` and set the width to 100%, that should give you what you're looking for.

```
footer = splitLayout(
    tags$div(
        selectInput("y", NULL, paste(strrep("x", 10), 1:10), width="100%")
    ),
    actionButton("ok", icon("trash")),
    cellWidths = c("85%", "15%"),
    cellArgs = list(style = "vertical-align: top")
),
```

[image: selectInput uses correct width]

Comment: Perfect +1! Thanks, FYI the `div` is not needed.