# Why do buttons stay on the same row but textInputs do not?

Tags: r, shiny

I want the buttons and the textinputs to be on the same row.  The buttons stay on  the same row but the textInputs go on new rows.  I can't see why.

```
ui  =   fluidPage(
    textInput("ti1", "TI1"),
    actionButton("Button1", "B1"),
    actionButton("Button2", "B2"),
    textInput("ti2", "TI2")
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui= ui, server=server)
```

Comment: I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637248/shiny-4-small-textinput-boxes-side-by-side) might help you.

Comment: Lovely lovely!!

Answer (score 3):

As shown below, `textInput()` wraps its output in an HTML `div` element while `actionButton` does not. The default behavior of `div` elements is to visually isolate their contents, here by, in effect, adding a line break before and after the element, which is what you are seeing.

```
textInput("ti1", "TI1")
## <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
##   <label for="ti1">TI1</label>
##   <input id="ti1" type="text" class="form-control" value=""/>
## </div>

actionButton("Button1", "B1")
##  <button id="Button1" type="button" class="btn btn-default action-button">B1</button>
```

If you'd like to have several text inputs on one line (and/or several action buttons each on their own lines) you can do so using the functions `fluidRow()` and `column()`, like so:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(width = 4,
               textInput("ti2", "TI2")),
        column(width = 4,
               textInput("ti1", "TI1"))
    ),
    fluidRow(actionButton("Button1", "B1")),
    fluidRow(actionButton("Button2", "B2"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui= ui, server=server)
```