# Multiple vertical noUiSliderInput side-by-side

Tags: r, shiny

I am a shiny newbie.
I am trying to make an app where the user can move the slider and select the values, like in this [sound equalizer example](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#multiple-vertical) or [colour picker example](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/).
But my app places the slider inputs on top of each other. Can someone help?
Codes:

```
#- Packages ----
#
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
#
#- App_UI ----
#
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("num", "Years", choices = seq(1,30,1))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("input_ui"),
      #tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)
#
#- App_Server ----
#
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$input_ui <- renderUI({
    num <- as.integer(input$num)
    lapply(1:num, function(i) {
        noUiSliderInput(
          inputId = paste0("Y", i), label = paste0("Y_", i),
          min = 0, max = 1000, step = 1,
          value = c(0, 300), margin = 100,
          orientation = "vertical",
          direction="rtl",
          width = "100px", height = "300px"
        )
    })
  })
}
#
#- App_RUN ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

PS: Ideally the user could also write the values in a text box or table, but that I leave for further improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637248/shiny-4-small-textinput-boxes-side-by-side), you can embed your inputs in a `div(style="display:inline-block", ...)`

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$input_ui <- renderUI({
    num <- as.integer(input$num)
    lapply(1:num, function(i) {
      div(style="display:inline-block",
          noUiSliderInput(
            inputId = paste0("Y", i), label = paste0("Y_", i),
            min = 0, max = 1000, step = 1,
            value = c(0, 300), margin = 100,
            orientation = "vertical",
            direction="rtl",
            width = "100px", height = "300px"
          ))
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much!